# Crear Carpeta Publica SpringMVC

Tags: mvc, api, spring, rest

En el proyecto actual tengo un webservice (API-REST) este tiene aparte un panel de control donde llenan los formularios para idetrar via web este webservice

el detalle esta en que no se como podria crear una carpeta publica ejemplo actualmente en el formulario que tengo ya solicito la imagen y la guardo en la carpeta

main/resource/static/ImagenesDelTalServicio/

ahora practicamente en una base de datos relaciono pues la ruta con el servicio asi podria saber exactamente la ruta del archivo y poder extraerlo pero no se como extraer o descargarlo alguna idea

Comment: Hola Pedro. ¿Pudiste solucionarlo? No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero me parece que estás tratando de guardar imágenes de dinámicas dentro de static que está hecho para imágenes  ...estáticas... XP   A lo que me refiero es que debes de guardar tus imágenes en el servidor(puede ser a la misma altura donde se encuentra tu proyecto ), de otra manera habrá problemas a la hora de empaquetar tu aplicación.  ¿Pero qué es lo que tienes? ¿Como guardas actualmente?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear este método dentro de tu controller para encontrar las imagenes que subes en una carpeta llama `upload` a la misma altura que tu directorio `src`.

```
@GetMapping("/uploads/{filename:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> verFoto(@PathVariable String filename) {

        Path pathFoto = Paths.get("uploads").resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath();
        log.info("pathFoto: "+ pathFoto);
        Resource recurso = null;
        try {
            recurso = new UrlResource(pathFoto.toUri());
            if (!recurso.exists()|| !recurso.isReadable()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("No se puede cargar la imagen: " + pathFoto.getFileName());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" +recurso.getFilename()+"\"")
                .body(recurso);
    }
```

Para subir los archivos puedes usar este otro metodo.

```
@PostMapping("/form")
    public String guardar(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult br, Map<String, Object> model,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {

        if (br.hasErrors()) {
            model.put("titulo", "Formulario de cliente");
            return "form";
        }

        if (!foto.isEmpty()) {

            String uniqueFilename = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + foto.getOriginalFilename();

            Path rootPath = Paths.get("upload").resolve(uniqueFilename);

            Path rootAbsolutPath = rootPath.toAbsolutePath();

            log.info("rootPath:" + rootPath);
            log.info("rootAbsolutPath: " + rootAbsolutPath);

            try {

                Files.copy(foto.getInputStream(), rootAbsolutPath);

                flash.addFlashAttribute("info", "Has subido correctamente " + uniqueFilename);
                cliente.setFoto(uniqueFilename);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String mensajeFlash = (cliente.getId() != null) ? "Cliente editado con éxito." : "Cliente creado con éxito.";

        clienteService.save(cliente);
        /**
         * Cierra la sesión que se empezo con @SessionAttributes('Clientes')
         */
        status.setComplete();

        flash.addFlashAttribute("success", mensajeFlash);
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }
```

Con thymeleaf accedes a la imágen con esta etiqueta:

```
<img th:src="@{'/upload/'} + ${cliente.foto}">
```

Es muy importante la arroba. Como comentario adicional en este código estoy definiendo el `@sessionAttributes` para no utilizar directamente el `id` con `type="hidden"`. Si no es tu caso hay que remover `status.setComplete();` y tambien hay que quitar `SessionStatus status` de los parámetros del método.